# Duplicate account on Area 51

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, area-51, linked-accounts

I created [a profile](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/133120/) on Area 51 recently.  Just went to use it, and ended up creating [a duplicate profile](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/134779/) instead.  Still seems linked to my main account on the user information pages, but has separate rep, and isn't following any proposals etc.

Also, the operation to request merging of accounts doesn't work on Area 51, as it thinks it's a meta site, and doesn't recognise it as being a valid SE site for a profile to live on either:

[image]

Update:

Last week I was able to continue using my original Area 51 account on the computer I had originally created it on, as it was still logged in.  Today however, I had been logged out.  Upon logging in using my usual Open ID provider (Google), it sent me to the new account.

As per the above, I can't request a merger of the profiles in the usual manner.  Can this 101 rep account be removed or merged with my main account please.

Comment: Perhaps you used different OpenID provider than the one you're using for the rest of the sites?

Comment: No - I only ever use Google.  Have Facebook linked too just in case, but have never used it to sign in yet.  One thing that was different was that it was the first time I'd signed in to Area 51 on this device (safari on iPad), since the SE app (doesn't appear to?) support Area 51.

Comment: The form expects the site profiles to be linked to the same site. That's why you're seeing a mismatch there - area51 isn't the same as discuss.area51. Having said that, this is thorny. Both your A51 profiles think they're associated with the same network account. Merging doesn't work because A51 is too old as a codebase... Should be able to delete the wrong profile and fix up account-level pointers to the right place, though. I'll look into that this afternoon.

Comment: Thanks @Anna - I hadn't even noticed that I was on the discuss site!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I set up a special case to handle situations like this - from now on, when we attempt a merge on Area 51 and both user profiles are linked to the same account, we will perform a "local" merge only instead of trying to kick off a full network merge like we normally do.

This *seems* to work. Your profiles were the first production test case. :)

Let me know if you see any further oddities.