# How did I end up with two Area 51 accounts, and can I get this fixed?

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, user-accounts

I already had an Area 51 account, but today, logging in the same way as usual (using Facebook login) on a system that hadn't visited Area 51 before, I ended up getting a brand new account instead of getting into my existing one.

The detail pages for [my old account](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/137416/hvd) and [my new account](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/140350/hvd) both show the same network profile, confirming that the system does still recognise the old one as mine.

Can these accounts be merged? Completely deleting the new account also works for me, if it means that logging in again will get me back into my old account.

Just as reported in [Duplicate account on Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255877/duplicate-account-on-area-51), I cannot use the Contact page in the Help Center to request a merge of these accounts. I get the same "this operation cannot be performed on a meta site; please continue on the main site." message.

Comment: Sit tight, I'm looking into it. :)

Comment: Both your profiles are linked to the same network account, so I'm gonna take a bit and figure out what went wrong - might be related to the new login code we've been releasing.

Comment: Heh, looks like I'm asking a tough question here. :)

Comment: Oh hey, I knew I was forgetting something... Really sorry, will look later tonight/tomorrow morning at latest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry it took me a while to get around to this. Your account should be all fixed up now.

As for what happened... I wish I had a good story here. All that happened, though, was that you had a wrong entry in the table we use to map users on various sites to an account. So when you went to log in on Area 51, that table cheerfully said you had no account and we made you a new one.

Comment: Thanks! And for the explanation too, it is a bit of a reassurance that it won't happen again to me in the future.